# PHP copy says file does not exist when it does

Tags: php, file, copy, not-exists

im using the following code;

```
if( ! file_exists( $path ) ) { die( "'" . $path . "' not vaild path"); }
copy( $path, ltrim($create_folder . ltrim($path, "./"), ".") );
echo "'" . $path. "' => '" . $create_folder . ltrim($path, "./") . "'<br />";
```

The first if statement returns true yet the copy function returns;

`Warning: copy('./files/c7a628cba22e28eb17b5f5c6ae2a266a/0003.css') [function.copy]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

`'./files/c7a628cba22e28eb17b5f5c6ae2a266a/0003.css' => './224efcdebda48350056af291f64a9311/files/8b571e7fbf9bacf4473024b11f78bc0dfiles/c7a628cba22e28eb17b5f5c6ae2a266a/0003.css'`

If anyone knows why it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might notice that your second half is missing a slash.  As in, one of your path elements is "8b571e7fbf9bacf4473024b11f78bc0dfiles" instead of "8b571e7fbf9bacf4473024b11f78bc0d/files".  Try `$create_folder . '/' . ltrim($path, "./")`

But the real answer is "your file actually does not exist.  No, really, PHP is correct".  It's just talking about the destination not existing; the source is fine.

Comment: `It's just talking about the destination not existing; the source is fine.` im a dummy

Comment: After an hour of getting the copy failed, (when other files copied OK) and using if(file_exists(...)){ to double-check file DID exist, the final sentence " ... it's just talking about the destination not existing ..." gave me a pointer to the problem; trying to copy to non-existant folder!